# How do I cultivate mushrooms in a home environment?

Tags: indoors, mushrooms

I'm a housewife, and I intend to cultivate mushrooms. I've heard that they can be cultivated and grown indoors without much time spent on them, as an amateur in a home environment.

Can someone please help me out and provide some steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to answer because of where you are, and it depends which part of the country, but I did find this information below regarding a scheme from the Indian Horticultural Insitute which might be useful to you:-

http://www.dnaindia.com/bangalore/report-now-grow-chem-free-mushies-at-home-1870989

In the UK, we buy mushroom growing kits, which come with a box, the soil and the fungi for seeding complete, but I'm not sure that sort of thing is available where you are.

Comment: Oyster mushroom kits would definitely be the way to start. They include everything you need. Otherwise you will have to pasteurize straw or sawdust, obtain mushroom spawn, inoculate and package, and then incubate.

Comment: @Bamboo - Wow, this is a perfect link provided.   As for me, I live in Kolkata city of India, which is very humid.   But with that being said, let me go around in markets and see if such type of mushroom packets are available in here.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThatIdiot - Yes, let me first search for any such type of mushroom kits, whichever is available in market. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @Knowledge Craving The humidity will work in your favor. I just found this video which might be relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oormRweSf3E  It seems there is a lot of mushroom cultivation in India. You should surely be able to find high quality mushroom spawn "locally."